# How to check if input comes null/empty

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if an input comes null/empty.

```
If input <= 100 And input > 0 And Not input = "" Then

   subjectsInt.Add(subjects(i), input)
   check = True

End If
```

I know in that code I am checking it as String but I already did `Not input = Nothing` and `Not input = 0` and I am getting an error:

> Run-time exception (line -1): Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>
> [System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here is the code in case you want to take a look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QvoAo

Comment: It has to be `AndAlso` and you have to test it first.  So `If Not input = "" AndAlso (input > 0 And input <= 100) Then`.  AndAlso provides *short-circuit* evaluation of an expression.  Always a good idea to program for a while with Option Strict On in effect btw, Nietzsche would type "asdf" to see that fail as well and use TryParse().

Comment: @HansPassant check the Edit part: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QvoAo

Comment: Why am I receiving a downvote? You guys are just abusing of that functionality. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Learn how to work with Option Strict On. You are declaring input as an integer but then you assign it to the return value of Console.ReadLine that returns a string finally you check if it contains an empty string. Option Strict On will stop you from doing these basic errors. By the way an Integer is never null.

Comment: [Are you two working on the same project??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291265/create-dynamic-variables-from-an-array)

Comment: @VisualVincent not actually but he was helping me out.

Comment: 1.  Add `Option Strict On` to the top of the code file 2. Fix Errors 3. Profit!

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer : Well that clarifies some things... As for your question: `Console.ReadLine()` never returns null, but an empty string (`""`). You would have to check that _before_ you put it in an Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have looked at your code and there are many problems, all caused by the freely approach to Data Types that VB.NET allows when you have Option Strict set to Off. In this context VB.NET allows you to assign the return value of Console.ReadLine to an Integer trying to help you adding an implicit conversion of the input. Of course if the user types ABCD this implicit conversion has no other way to inform you than triggering an Exception. So I really, really recommend you to use Option Strict set to On ([MSDN Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx))

Now with Option Strict On your code has a lot of errors, I have rewritten your code and then explain in comments the changes.

```vb
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World")

       ' I use a List of strings instead of an untyped array list
       Dim subjects As New List(Of String)() From  
       {
           "Math",
           "English", 
           "German"
       } 
       Dim subjectsInt As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer) 
       Dim i, input As Integer
       Dim check As Boolean

       For i = 0 To subjects.Count - 1
           check = False
           Do
               Console.WriteLine(subjects(i) & ": ")

               ' The input is passed to a string 
               Dim temp  = Console.ReadLine()

               ' Check if this string is really a number
               If Int32.TryParse(temp, input) Then
                  If input <= 100 And input > 0 Then
                       subjectsInt.Add(subjects(i), input)
                       check = True
                  End If
               End If
           Loop While check = False
       Next
       For i = 0 To subjects.Count - 1
          Console.WriteLine(subjects(i) & ": " & subjectsInt(subjects(i)))
       Next
       Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the `input` is an integer, you can't compare an integer with a string which is precisely what's happening.

Even if the string contains only digit, the type system doesn't convert it inferring from the operator.

In your example, `input = ""` input can never be "". You should change the type of input to a string and then check before converting it to an integer.

This would be a solution:

```
Dim integerInput As Integer    
Dim stringInput = Console.ReadLine()
If Integer.TryParse(stringInput, integerInput) AndAlso integerInput <= 100 And integerInput > 0 Then
```

To use **< > =** with an integer you need to convert the string:

```
If Integer.Parse(input) <= 100 And Integer.Parse(input) > 0 And Not input = "" Then
```

**Integer.Parse** will do the job.

Obviously, if your input is a string and it's not guaranteed that it is going to contain just digit you need either to do some check before or use **Integer.TryParse**.

The closest you can get to a null check with a value type is `EqualityComparer(Of Integer).Default.Equals(id, Nothing)`; unless you start using **Nullable**, but it would be too late as the code will fail on the `input = Console.ReadLine()` when you input a non-digit string.

Comment: `Integer.Parse will do the job` until the user enters "I like pie"

Comment: @Plutonix I assumed it was obvious that you need to do a check or use TryParse. I'll add an extra comment. But the post don't mention the source of `input`. Can even be guaranteed that it's an integer. There is no user input in the code posted.

Comment: Actually his `input` variable is of type Integer. Check his fiddle.

Comment: @VisualVincent didn't see the full code, I'll have a look. Should have been in the question.

Comment: @VisualVincent you're right, no need to check because it will fail even before...

Comment: @Uno : Indeed all the required code should be in the question's body.